# System.ArgumentException: 'hwnd cannot be IntPtr.Zero or null.'

Tags: c#, google-chrome, ui-automation

I am trying to retrieve the Chrome browser URLs which are currently opened. But I was getting which is currently opened and unable to get all opened. Please suggest here.

Also I am getting the error now saying that ***System.ArgumentException: 'hwnd cannot be IntPtr.Zero or null.'***

Please help me here on two things: 1) hwnd cannot be IntPtr.Zero or null.'2) How to get all chrome urls.(Note: I have opened only one chrome browser)

[image]
Thanks,
Indrasheker

Comment: what value are you getting for process.MainWindowHandle. i got a feeling you are getting a chrome background process without main window thus you are getting 0 for the handle.

Comment: @Steve :process.MainWindowHandle = 0x00000000

Comment: its possible that you have hit a rendering process that doesn't have a window.

Comment: there you go. the error is self explanatory. you are trying to bind to a 0x00000000 (zero) handle and you are getting null ref exception.  Chrome has a bunch background processes without window so you would have to loop thru them to find the right one.

Comment: @Steve : Thanks much. I understand and resolved the issue but I want to retrieve all the URLs in chrome. Please suggest